# Parse and split .txt file and export into .csv rows using Python

Tags: python, csv, parsing, text, split

I have a large text file full of notes that I would like to split and separate into individual rows using Python. I've gotten it to work somewhat, but it is adding one letter per cell in a .csv file, not the entire section. I've inserted the `@@@` characters to denote where each section needs to be split. For example, here's what my .txt file looks like:

```
@@@ jlkdlkjdlkjdalkjdalk @@@ 78278947298729874298742 @@@ llkdlaklkdalkdsa
@@@ nmczxmnczxmncz
```

I eventually want it exported into .csv so it would look like this:

```
ID | Reporttext

1  | jlkdlkjdlkjdalkjdalk 
2  | 78278947298729874298742 
3  | llkdlaklkdalkdsa
4  | nmczxmnczxmncz
```

Right now it's being exported like this: j l k d l k (and so on).

Here's my code:

import re, csv
    with open("thetext.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split("@@@"):
                 with open(r'theoutput.csv', 'a') as g:
                       writer = csv.writer(g)
                       writer.writerow(word)
                       print(word)

So just to reiterate, my problem is avoiding the spacing (e.g., t h i s ) when it exports.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your separator is '@@@', right? In any case did you try to use pandas to load your file and then exports it to csv?
`data = pd.read_csv('my_file.txt', sep="@@@ ", header=None)`
`pd.to_csv('my_new_file.csv')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do stripping and splitting on the `@` like,

```
$ cat txt2csv.py 
import csv

with open('some.txt') as file_, open('some_new.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    lines = [x for x in file_.read().strip().split('@') if x]
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerow(('ID', 'Reporttext'))
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        writer.writerow((idx, line.strip('@')))
```

And the input file,

```
$ cat some.txt 
@@@ jlkdlkjdlkjdalkjdalk @@@ 78278947298729874298742 @ llkdlaklkdalkdsa @@@ nmczxmnczxmncz
```

And the output file,

```
$ cat some_new.csv 
ID|Reporttext
1| jlkdlkjdlkjdalkjdalk 
2| 78278947298729874298742 
3| llkdlaklkdalkdsa 
4| nmczxmnczxmncz
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should open both files with one

```py
with open("thetext.txt") as f, open(r'theoutput.csv', 'a') as g:
```

```py
import csv
with open("thetext.txt") as f, open('theoutput.csv', 'a') as g:
    lines = [x for x in f.read().strip().split('@') if x]
    writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerow(('ID', 'Reporttext'))
    for lineNumber, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        writer.writerow((lineNumber, line.strip('@')))
```

Also you have to use

```py
lines = f.readlines()
```

Because what's happening now, is that python treats the txt file like a large string

Comment: Using `for line in f:` instead of `f.readlines()` is totally fine and even more memory friendly since it reads line by line instead of loading every line in an object beforehand.

Comment: That's very helpfull I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer from han solo you could do the line reading and splitting like this:

```
import csv

with open("thetext.txt") as txt, open('theoutput.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
  writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')

  writer.writerow(('ID', 'Reporttext'))
  id = 1
  for line in txt:
    words = line.strip().split("@@@")

      for word in words:
        writer.writerow((id, word.strip()))
        id += 1
```

This way you're reading your txt file line by line, then split it at the `@@@` before writing them word by word to your CSV file. You can even remove the leading `@@@` in your input file.

Comment: The code works, but the only problem is that the text is misaligned.  For example, "1" is showing up under ID, but so is some of the text.  I'd like them to be in separate columns so I can import this into a database.  Do I need to use Pandas or something to do this? Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: If you want a normal CSV file then you have to use a semicolon as delimiter. I will edit my answer accordingly. And you should remove the leading `@@@` in your file so the code above won't write empty cells.